# Match a key until the next valid key and the content in between

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I'm trying to do pattern matching to get content sections form a file. The valid pattern to match the beginning of a section is:

```
\{\{[ \t]*@(?<name>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)[ \t]*\}\}
```

Which will match strings like `{{ @MainContent }}` and `{{@Section1}}`, as well as some additional whitespace.

A file that contains these section declarations may look like this:

**sample-sections.html**

```
{{ @MainContent }}
<section class="detail">
    <p>
        Bacon ipsum dolor amet beef salami sirloin shankle tongue. Capicola bresaola hamburger chuck leberkas rump shankle frankfurter chicken jowl tri-tip ham hock. Sirloin cupim pork pork loin tail tongue. Ham kevin tri-tip tongue meatball kielbasa, boudin flank shank chicken tenderloin pork belly.
    </p>
</section>
{{ @End }}

{{ @Sidebar }}
    <div class="content">
        <h4>Right Sidebar</h4>
        ...
    </div>
{{ @end }}

{{ @Scripts }}
<script>
    console.log("Script Section Loaded.");
</script>
{{ @end }}
```

I'm able to get the sections out with the following Regex, but **is it possible to do this without needing the and closing tag?** Below is working code for getting the sections with the end tags:

```
string pattern = @"\{\{[ \t]*@(?<name>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)[ \t]*\}\}(?<value>(.|\n)*?)\{\{[ \t]*@(?:(?i)end)[ \t]*\}\}";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(View, pattern);

foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match in matches)
{
    context.Response.Write("\n\n\nMatch: " + match.Index + "\n" + match.Value);
}
```

The result should be as follows:

```
[
    {
        "name": "MainContent",
        "value": "\n<section>...</section>\n\n"
    },
    {
        "name": "Sidebar",
        "value": "\n\t<div..."
    },
    {
        "name": "Scripts",
        "value": "\nconsole..."
    }
]
```

Comment: What about htmlagility pack?

Comment: Yeah. I'm intentionally trying to write it myself, because I really only need small function and not the complete functionality of Liquid, Blade or the like.